# Finding shortest and longest paths between two vertices in a DAG

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, polynomial-time

Given an unweighted DAG (directed acyclic graph) $D = (V,A)$ and two vertices $s$ and $t$, is it possible to find the shortest and longest path from $s$ to $t$ in polynomial time?  Path lengths are measured by the number of edges.

I am interested in finding the range of possible path lengths in polynomial time.

Ps., this question is a duplicate of the StackOverflow question [Longest path in a DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712495/longest-path-in-a-dag).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the shortest path problem, if we do not care about weights, then [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is a surefire way.  Otherwise [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) works as long as there are no negative edges.

For longest path, you could always do [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) on the graph with all edge weights negated. Recall that Bellman-Ford works as long as there are no negative weight cycles, and therefore works with any weights on a DAG.

Comment: Bellman-Ford *is* a dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: @jmite Thanks for the answer! A combination of Bellman-Ford and Dijkstra's is definitely the way to go. I'd set each edge to weight of -1 to make Bellman-Ford work for me.

Comment: @Raphael yes, but I think there's a direct DP algorithm to find max path, instead of negating all the edge weights.

Comment: @jmite: Why, of course: just change Bellman-Ford to do the conversion online, or maximise, or...

Comment: By the way, I am not intuitively convinced that the NP-complete problem Longest Path is thus easily in P on DAGs. I'd appreciate a proof/reference/explanation.

Comment: @Raphael robowolverine's comment about adding -1 edge weights works since you don't get negative cycles and the least weight path is by construction the longest path.

Comment: Also there is a simpler and efficient DP algorithm for [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths)

Answer (score 8):

Let $n = |V(G)|$ and $m = |E(G)|$. Let $w(a \to b)$ denote the weight of the edge $(a \to b)$.  Suppose that you want to find the minimum and maximum path cost from $s$ to $t$.

Starting from $b := t$, perform the following:

1. If $b$ has already been visited, return the already computed $\min(b)$ and $\max(b)$. Otherwise mark $b$ as visited.
2. Determine and record $\min(b)$ and $\max(b)$ as follows.

   - If $b = s$, store $\min(s) := \max(s) := 0$.
   - Else set $$\begin{align*}\min(b) &:= \min_{a \to b} \Bigl[ w(a \to b) + \min(a) \Bigr] \\ \max(b) &:= \max_{a \to b} \Bigl[ w(a \to b) + \max(a) \Bigr]\end{align*}$$ ignoring vertices for which $\min(a) = \max(a) = \mathrm{inaccessible}$. When computing minimum and maximum over an empty set of edges (no inbound edges to $b$ at all, or all ignored), set $\min(b) := \max(b) := \mathrm{inaccessible}$.

You should be able to prove that this algorithm runs in time $O(m)$, neglecting the time required to initialise all of the vertex variables.

Comment: This recursive “pull” approach might be actually slower than the usual dynamic “push” approach and it needs a stack of linear size to handle the recursion. The usual approach is to take vertices in a topological order and improve the interim minimum and maximum for each neighbor of the current node. The current node always has the final value of minimum and maximum as all the inbound edges must have already been used to improve them.